# Simplest way to get date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

For instance in C# there is

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Which will output exactly what it looks like in one short concise line, is there something like that with javascript or jQuery that doesn't require handling each part of the date and time and formatting each bit to have 2 digits etc..

I am new to javascript and jQuery and I think it will save a lot of time if I found out the best way to handle dates and time but after looking around and not finding any answers I am guessing there's no vanilla solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best and easiest way to handle dates in javascript is including [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to your project. You can then output the date with

```
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss");
```

for example

Answer (score 2):

Date() will give you the current local data and time, but its formatting ability isn't great as browser support is limited.

Try: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this without using an outside library is:

```
var d = new Date(1993, 6, 28, 14, 39, 7);
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.toDateString());
```

from which you would get:

```
Wed Jul 28 1993 14:39:07 GMT-0600 (PDT)
Wed Jul 28 1993
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of libraries around, some handle CLDR notation and some don't. `moments.js` uses it's own formatting codes. But an example of a library that I have been working on, that does support CLDR notation is

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        'astrodate': '//rawgit.com/Xotic750/astrodate/master/lib/astrodate'
    }
});

require(['astrodate'], function (AstroDate) {
    "use strict";

    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new AstroDate().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/minified/require.js"></script>
```

ok, that was using the library as a module but it could just be included in the html.

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new AstroDate().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')));
```

```html
<script src="http://rawgit.com/Xotic750/util-x/master/lib/util-x.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/Xotic750/astrodate/master/lib/astrodate.js"></script>
```